# Higher precision doubles and trigonometric functions in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

According to IEEE the following doubles exist:

```
                Mantissa   Exponent  
double 64bit:       52 bit     11 bit  
double 80bit:       64 bit     15 bit
```

In Java only the 64bit double can be directly
stored in an instance variable. I would like for 
whatever reason work with 80bit floats as defined 
above in Java. I am interested in the full set 
of arithmetic functions, I/O and **trigonometric**
functions. How could I do that?

One could of course do something along the 
following lines:

```
public class DoubleExt {
    private long mantissa;
    private short exponent;
}
```

And then make a package that interfaces with
some of the known C libs for 80bit floats.

But would this be considered the best practice? 
What about supporting a couple of plattforms
and architectures?

Bye

Comment: are you talking about something like strictfp class?

Comment: There is a class StrictMath which implements the 64bit double. But I am asking for 80bit double. I also noticed a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277309/java-floating-point-high-precision-library But I am especially interested also of a coverage of trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure primitives won't get you there, but the [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class is as good as it gets (for everything except trigonometry).

For trigonometric functions, however, you will have to resort to an external library, like [APFloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173512/java-bigdecimal-trigonometric-methods)).

Comment: I didn't see some trigonometric functions in BigDecimal. But otherwise with a custom MathContext, this would probably do.

Comment: Ok, I see there is a ApfloatMath.sin for example. Ok, have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps BigDecimal is an adequate way for you. But I believe it doesn't provide the full set of mathematic functions.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is already 5 years old. Time to look around
whether there are some new candidates, maybe draw inspiraction
from other languages.

In Racket we find a BigFloat data type:
https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/bigfloat.html

The underlying library is GNU MPFR, a Java interface was started:
https://github.com/kframework/mpfr-java

Is this the only interface so far?