# function to multiply very small or very big numbers

Tags: java, android

How can I multiply by a *10^(-20). I couldn't find any logarithmic functions so I hope there will be some others

Comment: Java `doubles` cover the range 4.9*10^-324 to 1.7*10^308, positive or negative. Is that enough? If so, you can just use the normal `*` operator.

Comment: And the Math utility class has plenty of logarithmic methods, but I support Douglas' comment, which if it were an answer, I'd up-vote it.

Comment: You mean multiply a by 1e-20 ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277309/java-floating-point-high-precision-library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a log function, I would use Math.pow

```
 double d = a * Math.pow(10, -20);
```

Comment: Java supports floating point literals, so you could write: `a * 1.0e-20`

Answer (score 3):

Java `doubles` cover the range 4.9*10^-324 to 1.7*10^308, positive or negative. If your numbers fit within that range, and you are happy to use floating point precision, you can use the normal `*` operator.

The documentation for the `Math.log` method is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class which can store large values for your calculations.

Comment: Why was this answer given a minus 1?  Where in the OP does he mention floating point values?  Has the question been modified recently?  Even if he was using floating point numbers, doing calculations on very small numbers and using floating point causes a lot of problems you can avoid by using a class like BigDecimal.  That's the point, to keep the accuracy and avoid the issues that arise with floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @JimLewis - There is no prevention using BigDecimal when doing calculations with floats/doubles - on the contrary, it is much safer and reduces pitfalls of using float and double types.  Take a look in [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world)

Comment: @inistel: I was misled by the first sentence in the link in your original answer, which states "This class represents immutable integer numbers of arbitrary length."  But I see now that it is capable of representing non-integers as well.  I still think it's not the solution the OP should be looking into, but I'll happily rescind the downvote.