# Divide A number per 5, getting the weight ratio and using it to split another number

Tags: java, math, decimal, precision

An example will clear the idea:

number A = 12
number B = 20

I need to divide A per 5 until I dont go less than 5. So I get 3 parts: 5,5 an 2.
Now I have to use this result to split B given the weight just calculated.
So 20 * (5/12), 20 * (5/12), 20* (2/12) and their sum of course must be exactly equal to B (20 in our case)

I have to do this without losing any precision and trying to have the result as much correct as possible. My example is using int, but I need to do that with decimals as well.(A could be 12.37 and B could be 20.13 for instance) Anyone knows a library or a hint to do that ?

Comment: So just to get this right (the example is rather confusing - e.g. what does "divide A per 5 until I don't go less than 5" mean?): you want a sequence of numbers `(a1, a2, ..., an)`, such that all elements are `<= 5` and `a1 / A * B + a2 / A * B + ... + an / A * B = B` and `a1 + a2 + ... + an = A`? In addition: does the sequence only contain integers, or are doubles  valid as well?

Comment: Have you looked at java BigDecimal and BigInteger?

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right, the description is bad. When I say that I need to divide by 5, it means until I can do it with % equals to 0.  So if A is 16 --> 5,5,5,1 if A is 6 I get 5 and 1, if A is 13 I get 5,5 and 3. The sequence can contains double. It is fine. But we need to pay attention as working with decimals is risky.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question (at least the way I understand it) is pretty simple to solve:

What we've got: `A` and `B`, which may be decimal
What we want: a sequence `(a1, a2, ..., an)` with the following properties:

- any element of the sequence is smaller equal 5
- all elements sum up to `A`: `a1 + a2 + ... + an = A`
- `a1 / A * B + a2 / A * B + ... + an / A * B = B`

Well time for a bit of math:

```
B = //RHS => LHS
a1 / A * B + a2 / A * B + ... + an / A * B = //factorize
(a1 + a2 + ... + an) / A * B =  //(a1 + a2 + ... + an) = A
B
```

Or in other words: use whatever sequence you like. As long as the elements of the sequence sum up to `A` and are all smaller-equal to `B` you're fine.

As for the precision:
Using the type of the input there shouldn't be any issue with precision, as the output can be built in a manner to only consist of integers and the decimal part of the input (so actually your output might have a better -unused - precision than the input).

So to generate the values `a1 / A * B, a2 / A * B, ...` we need to do the following:
Use `BigDecimal` for maximum-precision - beware though, as `B / A` may be periodic! The rest works just the usual way, except that you need to use methods instead of normal operators:

- `a + b` with BigDecimal would be `a.add(b)`
- `a * b` with BigDecimal would be `a.multiply(b)`
- ...

You can look up the details in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. I need exactly these values : 20 * (5/12), 20 * (5/12), 20* (2/12) , so with your algorith how I can get them ?

Comment: @darkRevan85 You mean you want the values created by multiplying elements of the sequence with `A / B`? Well, the main-problem, which I've already shown in my answer is that there is no distinct way of splitting `A` up. In fact there's an infinite number of ways. E.g.: for `A = 10`, you could use the sequence `(5, 5)`, or `(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, -15)` or `(3.33, 3.33, 3.33)`. So you'll first have to decide how you'll get that sequence in a distinct way.

Comment: The sequence must be like I said. I must divide by 5. Only the sequence (5,5) is correct in your example. If I had 11.77, the sequence must be 5,5,1.77

Comment: Yep, BigDecimal are good for that, I wonder if there is an easy way to use long to avoid bad performances.

Comment: @darkRevan85 not really. Of course you could use `long` to represent a [fixed-point-decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). But this comes with a few limitations, both in terms of maximum representable decimal places and precision. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916308/fixed-point-arithmetics-in-java-with-fast-performance) covers that topic in detail.

Answer (score 0):

after reading your question, i cant figure out what is that you want.
Do you want the sequence of 5,5,5,..n(where n<5) for A or B,and also the thing about sum for B is it a condition or is that what you are trying to achieve ?

anyway if its the sequence that you want then you could do this :

```
int A,B;            //if A=12
int numOfFives=A/5; // then numOfFives=2
int remainder=A%5;  //then remainder=2
```

using this method will ensure that the last number will always be less than one.

so you could do the sum like :

```
sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<numOfFives;i++){
sum+=B*(5d/12d); // 5/12 with sum as int gives result sum =0 , so change the fraction part accordingly to your need. 
}
sum+=B*(remainder/12d);
```

if you want the sequence then do :

```
System.out.println("Sequence = ");
for(int i=0;i<numOfFives;i++){
System.out.println(5+",");
}
System.out.println(remainder);
```

also make your calulation of sequence much easier.

**Edit 1**

here is the [Live Program on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/wvtdhc) if you want to check it out.

```
inputs :
A=12
B=20

outputs:
Final Sum=20.0
Sequence=5,5,2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is good but I need to support decimals numbers. (both A and B)

Comment: the `5d/12d` gives an answer in double which has decimals places upto 15 digits you want more ?  for decimal support all you have to do is initialize `A`,`B`,`sum` with the type `double`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Example {

    public static void main (String[]args) { 
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("16.3");    
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("20");
        BigDecimal[] div_rem = a.divideAndRemainder(new BigDecimal("5"));
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<div_rem[0].intValue();i++){
           s += b +" * (5/"+a+"), ";
        }
        s += b +" * ("+div_rem[1]+"/"+a+")";
        System.out.println(s);

        System.out.println(b +" * (5/"+a+") = " + b.multiply(new BigDecimal("5").divide(a, 5,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
        System.out.println(b +" * ("+div_rem[1]+"/"+a+") = " + b.multiply(div_rem[1].divide(a,5 ,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
    }            
}
```