# Power precision in Java

Tags: java, precision

I'm trying to perform a power calculation in Java for exponent that is less than 1, for example: (2^0.333)
but when i calculate that in Java, i got a result with less precision than if i do the same calculation on a normal calculator.

in Java

```
double f = Math.pow(2.0,0.333);
System.out.println(f);

//output
//1.2596299799473993
```

in a normal calculator i got

```
//output
//1.2596299799473993502546921425703
```

how can I get the same result in java without losing precision?

any help is appreciated

Comment: what is a normal calculator? how do we know that your calculator is not abnormal? =)

Comment: i mean by normal calculator = Windows Calculator

Comment: Maybe you should try looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277309/java-floating-point-high-precision-library

Comment: I think ApfloatMath is the app I'm looking for, thanks Artem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in floating point arithmetic in Java is of limited precision. The built-in [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class doesn't provide the operations that you need (real exponentiation, or even logs). You can use a third-party app such as [Apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/) (see the `ApfloatMath` class) or [JScience](http://jscience.org/), both of which can do the exponentiation calculation to arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1):

A more precise value cannot be acquired with primitive doubles alone.  Instead, use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which is used to represent arbitrarily *precise* floating-point values.

Note that you will need a custom `pow` function to handle BigDecimal.  One implementation can be found [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579779/how-to-do-a-fractional-power-on-bigdecimal-in-java#3590314).

Comment: This isn't very useful. How would you propose doing exponentiation of two `BigDecimal` quantities?

Comment: @TedHopp I actually began writing a method `pow(BigDecimal val, double exponent, int precision)` before realizing that wouldn't work.  I'm researching how to do so reasonably.  EDIT: Found one.

Answer (score 0):

A double-precision floating point value, like the one you're using in your Java code, can only accurately represent 15 to 17 significant digits. Unless the Windows calculator app you're using is using a higher-precision data type internally (which is unlikely), those digits are likely to be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use BigDecimal and set precision.

```
   BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal(2.0);

   BigDecimal exp = new BigDecimal(0.3333);

   BigDecimal resul = new BigDecimal((Math.pow(base.doubleValue(),exp.doubleValue()))).setScale(31,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("resul "+ resul);
```