# have_header from mkmf throws an error in Jruby

Tags: jruby, ruby-c-extension

I have this test code :

```
require 'mkmf'

puts have_header("iostream.h")
```

this code throws an error in Jruby like this :

> checking for iostream.h... RuntimeError: The compiler failed to generate an executable file. You have to install development tools first.
>
> try_do at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:456
>    try_cpp at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:587
>   block in have_header at
>   /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1091
>   block in checking_for at
>   /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:942
>         block in postpone at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:350
>                      open at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:320
>         block in postpone at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:350
>                      open at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:320
>                  postpone at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:346
>              checking_for at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:941
>               have_header at /home/abd/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.1.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1090
>                     at test.rb:3

I have no idea what does it mean by development tools and I searched the internet without finding anything about this.

I installed Jruby 9.1.6.0 through rvm, this is my java version :

```
[abd@abd testruby]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_112"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

I'm using Arch linux here.

The real reason behind my question is that I tried installing gmp gem and native extensions wouldn't build because of the same error, I know the gem is unmaintained but I want to resolve this issue anyway because the above message suggests that my installation is lacking.

By the way I have the jdk, not just the jre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRuby C extensions have been deprecated [and possibly removed already but I'm a bit out of the loop].

Since you're running on the JVM, have you considered the alternatives? i.e. either use Java's `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` if the performance is adequate for your needs, or wrap GMP using JNI / JNA- it looks like [somebody has tried](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-devel/2012-November/002628.html) already. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277309/java-floating-point-high-precision-library) SO question for a few more Java alternatives.